# How to force Doxygen not to process the text in a code section of a markdown file?

Tags: markdown, doxygen

In the main page of my documentation, written in markdown, I want to put some examples showing how to comment the code in the project.

Basically I expect to have the same output on my HTML file than here on SO, i.e. some raw commented code in the Code Sample view :

```
/** @brief Brief description of what the function does
*
* @details This section describes in more details the purpose 
* of the function and its role into the module. 
* 
* @param [in] bar the number to deal with
* @retval the result of some operation
*/
uint8_t foo(uint8_t bar) {
}
```

To achieve that I basically put the code in my markdown file with 4 spaces on the left of each line.

The problem is that Doxygen seems to process these lines as it would do in a standard source file and I end up with this :

[image]

Is there a way to tell Doxygen to treat these lines as plain text but still to put them in the code view ? I was able to do that with the numbered code view (\code and \endcode) but I don't like this solution since it's harder to copy-paste the content of this view due to the line numbers being taken in the selection.

The exact content of my file is here on pastebin : [markdown.md](http://pastebin.com/LYN72hDS)

All I want is that : 
[image]

But without the line numbers feature.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? In the 1.8.12 version some improvements regarding the use of code segments etc. have been incorporated. In case the problem still does occur, please show the used code including (the differences to the default doxyfile) or create a (small) self-contained example (source+config file in a tar or zip) that allows us to reproduce the problem on bugzilla (http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/trouble.html#bug_reports)

Comment: @albert I reproduced it right now with the 1.8.12 version. I've edited my answer, the problem should be more comprehensible and I've added the markdown file on pastebin.

Comment: @albert Note that it's funny because at work with the 1.8.11 version the `\code ... \endcode` balise will output a code section with line numbers, but at home with the version 1.8.12 I have the code section I want. Is there a way to have this code section for sure ? I wouldn't like it to change at the next Doxygen update.

Comment: That you don't have the problem in 1.8.12 is probably due to "In the 1.8.12 version some improvements regarding the use of code segments etc. have been incorporated." The rest I have to have a look at later on.

Comment: I just checked with the current master version from github and this looks OK, it is seen as code (although I don't like the shown characters, when placing a block of triple back ticks around it it looks quite nice (in the 1.8.14 version there are still problems with both types of output).